# I get an error "Attempting to play invalid Qt resource" when I try to play a mediafile which is not in the qrc

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

Of course, if I include the particular mediafile in qrc file, then the following qml program seems to detect it.

I want the user to select the media file he wants through a file browser, and play it.

So, currently, I passed the file path in the form of a string as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Rectangle
{
    id:     head
    width:  500
    height: 500

    property int    heightOfButtons: 50
    property int    widthOfButtons: 50
    property string videoSource: "/home/*****/1.mp4"

    Video
    {
        id: video
        width : head.width
        height : head.height
        source: head.videoSource

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: { video.play() }
        }

        onErrorStringChanged: console.log("errorstring: " + errorString)
        focus: true
    }

    Grid
    {
        columns: 1; columnSpacing: 10
        Rectangle
        {
            height: head.heightOfButtons; width: head.widthOfButtons; color: "green"
            id: playStop
            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: video.playbackState == MediaPlayer.PlayingState ? video.pause() : video.play()}
            Text {color: "white"; text: "Play/Pause";  anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter}
        }

        Rectangle
        {
            height: rightGrid.heightOfButtons; width: rightGrid.widthOfButtons; color: "red"
            id: stop
            MouseArea {anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: video.stop()}
            Text {color: "white"; text: "Stop";  anchors.right: parent.right; anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;}
        }
    }
}
```

File exists, but the programs shows the error:

`qml: errorstring: Attempting to play invalid Qt resource`

**How to play the file which the user selects dynamically?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to give the path of the mediafile as:

`property string videoSource: "file:///home/***/1.mp4"`

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html